# React native use latest commit on master for a dependency

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, package.json, react-native-community

I want [this fix](https://github.com/react-native-art/art/pull/70) for `react-native-art/art` crashing on `(void)setShadow:(ARTShadow)shadow`. But there has been no public release after `v1.2.0` to include this fix. I have confirmed the fix works by manually adding the diff. But this is not a long-term solution. Does `react-native` support defining dependencies via branch and commit instead of version tags?

Currently, the dependency is defined like this:

```
{
...
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@react-native-community/art": "1.2.0",
    ...
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really related to `react-native`, but to how `npm` dependencies get installed.

Using `git` URLs is supported so you can point dependencies to any repo, and if necessary to specific branches or even specific commits.

If you want to get whatever's on master you can set your dependency like so:

```
"@react-native-community/art": "git+https://github.com/react-native-art/art.git"
```

You can see the full `npm` documentation regarding Github URLs [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

Comment: Let me try this out. Thanks a lot! :D